# Get Total Associated Record Count Across Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, union, left-join, inner-join

I have the following query that UNIONs two tables which contains tags associated with two separate entities: cat and dog. I am trying to create a table that lists tags and the number of times their appear across two tables. This is a normalized tagging system, so only the tag ID is referenced in the cat_tags and dog_tags tables, and that's why I am doing another INNER JOIN to get the actual tag value.

```
SELECT x.tag_id, (COUNT(y.tag_id) + COUNT(z.tag_id)) AS num, tag_name AS tag
FROM (SELECT dt.tag_id FROM dog_tags dt UNION SELECT st.tag_id FROM cat_tags st) x
LEFT JOIN dog_tags y ON y.tag_id = x.tag_id
LEFT JOIN cat_tags z ON z.tag_id = x.tag_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON x.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY x.tag_id ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

The problem is that the num counts are not correct for tags that appear multiple times across the two tables. For example tag ID number 5 ("collar") appears twice in cat_tags and twice in dog_tags, however the above query gives the total count as 8 instead of 4. Another tag that appears three times comes out as 6. Something is multiplying them by 2. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is really complicated and you could try something like this:

```
  SELECT tag_id
       , tag_name
       , sum(num) as num
    FROM tags
    join
      (
          SELECT tag_id, count(*) as num FROM dog_tags GROUP BY tag_id
          union all
          SELECT tag_id, count(*) as num FROM cat_tags GROUP BY tag_id
      ) as AnimalsCount on AnimalsCount.tag_id = tags.tag_id
GROUP BY tag_id
       , tag_name -- you can remove this if you are 100% sure is not necessary
```

BTW check the difference between `union` and `union all`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html.

Comment: Thanks. That worked too. Based on the query times I am getting I am not sure which of the two responses is more optimized. Can you point out the advantages of your solution?

Comment: Too see which query is more efficient you can use `EXPLAIN`. You also can add test data to have a good number of rows and then the times will be different. I don't know if my query is more efficient but for me the main advantage is that is more clear. Am I being subjective?, maybe :D

Comment: In the end I chose your query. But I figured out that yours doesn't include tags that don't exist in the dog_tags and cat_tags tables (the other one does). So how can we modify your query so that it includes tags that aren't used?

Comment: In that case you need to change `join` by `left join`. `left join` will include all rows on the left table (`tags`) whether or not they are on the right table (subquery `AnimalsCount`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.tag_id, t.tag_name as tag,
    ifnull(dc.dog_total, 0) + ifnull(cc.cat_total, 0) as num
from
    tags t
    left join (
        select tag_id, count(*) as dog_total
        from dog_tags
        group by tag_id
    ) as dc on t.tag_id = dc.tag_id
    left join (
        select tag_id, count(*) as cat_total
        from cat_tags
        group by tag_id
    ) as cc on t.tag_id = cc.tag_id
order by num desc
limit 0, 100
```

Well, the problem was the joins you have in your query. Because you weren't grouping by `tag_id` for each source table. So, if `collar` appeared 2 times in `dog_tags` and 3 in `cat_tags` the join would result in 6 rows that share the same `tag_id`, so the counts would be wrong.  Remember that a join is a *Cartesian product* of the rows of each joined table with a certain criteria. So, by grouping first by `tag_id` for each source table, we ensure that the `tag_id` appears only once in each table or *derived table*. And when we join the tables each `tag_id` will produce a single row.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I understand that you approached the problem the best way you knew how to, but can you point out why exactly my query returns the wrong results and if we had to, how would we fix the original query?

Also, I corrected the "cc" alias in your query to "ct".